# How to convert and calculate values using Converters in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, typeconverter

I have a set of units of `Pressure` namely

```
hPA(hectopascal),mb(mbar),InHg(Inch of mercury),mmHg(milimeter of Mercury),Pa(Pascals)
```

I want to allow the user to select any of the above `mentioned` unit and the input gets changed accordingly.

BY default `hPA` would be selected and later he can switch the units and the output value get recalculated and shown as the output.

Example:
Case 1: User receives the value of 100`(value is received from server so it wont change during the application)` and doesn't change the unit. So the default shown is `100 hPA` as `hPA` was set as default choice. Later, he comes and changes it to Pa and the output changes to `10000 Pa`. He can later change it to `mb` or anything he likes from the available units.

In this screenshot, I have added a radio button group for all the group:

[image]

How can I write the Converter for this in C#? My understanding in converters is of basic level.

Comment: Is this question different from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652707/stuck-in-valueconverter-implementation-in-uwp-application) Question?

Comment: someone mentioned that the question was not clear so added a new one

Comment: Does the server always send the same unit (for example hPa), or it can change? Can user change the value or only unit? - you have a TextBox there and written that `so it wont change during the application`.

Comment: @Romasz give me sometime. I would update my question with what all I have attempted. Currently I am writing methods to convert the value from one unit to other. What I think Is lets have a value in one unit and convert to others and vice versa